# Wod document Line spacing in header is not being affected

Tags: vba, ms-word

any idea why these two lines are not changing / setting the line spacing in my document's header section:

```
Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Paragraphs(1).LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceExactly
Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Paragraphs(1).LineSpacing = 8
```

Thanks
Syed

Comment: I've occasionally run into misunderstandings about what "Line spacing" really is... What do you expect should happen? If you change the setting as a user do you see the effect you expect? If yes, which commands did you use in the UI?

Comment: @Smiqbal what you are doing is setting the height of the paragraph to exactly 8 points. If your paragraph font size is anything greater than 11 points, then you will be decapitating it. When the spacing rule is on exactly, then if for example, you wanted double spacing on text set with an 11 point font, your line spacing would have to be 22. Are you sure you want to set line spacing? Have you looked at Spaces Before or After?

Comment: Hi Cindy and Rich, Thanks for your responses. My font size is also 8 points. I have somehow fixed this issue by keeping font size as 8 point and line spacing as 6 points through VBA code. I have encountered another challenge that I will share with community by posting another question here.

Comment: Cindy, trying to create & format a header of my target doc at run time for an unascertained number of pages based on actual values from a table (source doc) through script. Finally, where I am stuck at the moment is that I am trying to use printout command in my inner for-next loop which sends a variable as my target doc's header text. Experiencing some weird results in ordering of page Nos. & even print spool was completely choked after printing first 10 pages or so during testing. Surprisingly, all went OK during testing in msg boxes & debugs. Do I need a wait timeout b/w printout commands?